# React native live stream and save live stream video

Tags: react-native, webrtc, live-streaming, react-native-webrtc

I have to create an app to live stream and save live stream video.

> An app ( which is simple version of cam app as Botslab/Mi home/ ... ) just lives every time, saves video (maybe every 20 mins) to memory stick and watches saved videos on App

I plan to use [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc) for the project.

But when I read docs, it has a problem: `mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` can help to record video but my skill is not good enough so I can't find a way to use it in React Native.

I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082227/14745811 but it can't stream HD or fullHD quality

So does anyone have any suggestions?

Of course, a free option because I use my company server.